# How Much Time spent on websites of user

Tags: 7, users

In website have many AUTHENTICATED USER. I want to how many times spent of each user on site.

I use login history module, it show only every login time of all user.

I use time spent module, but not track all time of every page.

Please suggest how to calculate time spent of each user on every login.

Comment: What do you mean by "time spent" exactly? If a user opens up a web page, then leaves it open for 24 hours, is that "time spent" on your site? If not, where's the cut-off? I think you need to define this a lot better if you want an answer that's going to address your actual problem. Otherwise people are just going to guess what you mean

Answer (score 3):

Seems the [Time Spent](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_spent)  module is what you're looking for

> This module tracks, by Ajax, how long a registered user took to read a page and the amount of time he spent on the entire site.
>
> You can configure which content type and role should be tracked and view the report, exhibiting the total hours (or minutes/seconds) a user spent reading a page and at the entire site.

Similar module -[Time Tracker](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_tracker)

> **Features**
>
> - Track Time on any entity and or comments
> - Activities and Time Entries are now both fieldable entities.
> - Track time using time intervals (start and end times) or durations    (admin/settings/time_tracker)
> - Integrated Timer to track time as you go
> - Time estimating
> - User Time Sheets to display weekly logged time (user/%uid/time_sheet)
> - View for reporting on tracked time (time/report)

Comment: Time Tracker module only handle any node or any nodes comments

Comment: that what i say

Comment: @RiturajKumar Time Spent is that what you need but if you are very visitor it cause too load on your website performance.

Comment: Krishna Mohan, you solution is good. vote up. but he should care about performance.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan you're welcome,yes, you right